# Uncaught Error: Class "DOMImplementation"

Tags: php, debian, apache2, dompdf

I have an app php mvc run 'OK' in xammp with apache2. But now i need to move to debian server 11 with apache2, php 8.1.

with the page that generates the report in pdf i had the Uncaught Error: Class "DOMImplementation" in log of apache2.
I searched for this error on google, but the answers didn't work for me.

My code generate a html page, i test it by echo and is ok but dont to generate pdf.

My code to call dompdf is some like this:

```
class xyz
{
use Exception;
use PDO;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

public function montaPDF($inform)
{
        $options = new Options();
        $options->isFontSubsettingEnabled(false);
        $options->isRemoteEnabled(true);
        $pdf = new Dompdf($options);
        $html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="pt-br">
                    <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    </head><body>';         
        $html .= '</body></html>';                  
        $pdf->loadHtml($html); **//the error occur in this part**
        
                $pdf->render();
        $pdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

}
}
```

thank you all in advance, for read and try to help!!

Comment: Make sure you have the PHP-XML extension installed and enabled

Comment: When importing namespaces, you need to do that outside of the class

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you! but the classes are ok, remember the entire app works 100% when is in xammp, i missed instaled ou enabled something in debian. The real USES is outside the class. Thank you

Comment: Hi aynber, thank you, how can i check this i search in php.ini loaded and cant found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all!Specialy aynber! Solved!

sudo apt-get install php8.1-xml : Worked.